# 403 Error While Uploading or Getting Images - Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

It was working few days back, uploading and displaying images to firebase. But now with every upload it gives me error with code `403`.

[image]

Here are my storage rules in firebase:

```
service firebase.storage {
   match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{userId}/{postId}/{fileName} {
     allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
     allow read;
    }
  }
}
```

PS: user is logged in while uploading and displaying images. **It do not let me upload images either**

Stuck, help required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it myself by changing storage rules to public

Not a secure approach but resolved my error:

```
service firebase.storage {
   match /b/your-app-name.appspot.com/o {
     match /{allPaths=**} {
      // Allow access by all users
      allow read, write;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: That means that if someone discovers the URL for you bucket, they can upload/download whatever they want. I'd recommend figuring out the real source of the problem, and fixing this security risk.